# How do I update the upload progress percentage in the recyclerview items?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to upload a list of files from my application to amazon s3 bucket. I can get the upload progress but I was not able to set the upload progress value in the recycler view item. (I want to show the file sharing progress like Shareit application while sharing files to another device.)

I have implemented recyclerview and it works fine. I have a progress bar and Textview on each file that is going to get uploaded. I just want to show the upload progress in the progress bar and in the text view on each item.

```
public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
    if (state.COMPLETED.equals(observer.getState())) {

        Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "File Upload Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
    long _bytesCurrent = bytesCurrent;
    long _bytesTotal = bytesTotal;

    float percentage = (int) ((float)_bytesCurrent /(float)_bytesTotal * 100);
    Log.d("percentage","" + percentage);

}

@Override
public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "" + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("ErrorMessage","" + ex.getMessage());

}
```

//Below Recyclerview adapter code

```
public class FileListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<FileListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
public static ArrayList<String> filePaths;
private RecyclerViewClickListener clicklistener;
private int rowLayout;
private Context mContext;
private ImageView fileThumbnail, fileEdit, fileRemove;
private TextView filePath, fileSize, uploadPrtg;
public ProgressBar uploadProgs;
private int Progress;
private String ProgPos;

public FileListAdapter(ArrayList<String> filePaths, int rowLayout, Context context) {
    this.filePaths = filePaths;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.rowLayout = rowLayout;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (ProgPos != null && ProgPos.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(position))){
        uploadProgs.setProgress((int) Progress);
        uploadPrtg.setText((int)(Progress)+"%");
    }
    Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
    File file = new File(filePaths.get(position));
    String path = filePaths.get(position);

    String extension2 = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("/"));
    filePath.setText(extension2);

    long length = file.length() / 1024;
    fileSize.setText("Size :- " + length + " KB");




    String extension = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));

    if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".mp4")){
        fileEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (path != null) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(path)
                .into(fileThumbnail);
    } else {
        fileThumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_photo);
    }
}

public void updateProgress(float percentage, int position){
    ProgPos = String.valueOf(position);
    Progress = (int) percentage;
    filePaths.set(position, String.valueOf(percentage));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filePaths.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        fileThumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.file_thumbnail);
        filePath = view.findViewById(R.id.file_path);
        fileSize = view.findViewById(R.id.file_size);
        fileEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.editMyvid);
        fileRemove = view.findViewById(R.id.removeMyFile);
        uploadProgs = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        uploadProgs.setMax(100);
        uploadPrtg = view.findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);

        fileEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        view.setTag(view);
        fileEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
        fileRemove.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (clicklistener != null) {
            clicklistener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }

    }
}

public void setClickListener(RecyclerViewClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clicklistener = itemClickListener;
}

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View v, int position);

}

public void removeAt(int position) {
    filePaths.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, filePaths.size());
}
```

If anyone wants the recyclerview adapter code I can update it too. Please help me to get it done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is int id, in  "onProgressChanged" ?   is this recyclerview Item id?

Comment: Add your adapter code in question

Comment: @GaneshPokale I have added the Adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
    long _bytesCurrent = bytesCurrent;
    long _bytesTotal = bytesTotal;

    float percentage = (int) ((float)_bytesCurrent /(float)_bytesTotal * 100);
    Log.d("percentage","" + percentage);
   adapter.updateProgress(percentage, position);// pass adapter list item position here 
}
```

Adapter change
Instead of `ArrayList<String> filePaths` use `ArrayList<FilesClass> filePaths` and update your adapter accordingly

FilesClass.java

```
public class FilesClass {
    String FileName;
    Float Percentage;

    public FilesClass(String fileName, Float percentage) {
        FileName = fileName;
        Percentage = percentage;
    }

    public FilesClass() {
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return FileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    public Float getPercentage() {
        return Percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(Float percentage) {
        Percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

and Add your file path and default progress 0. after using this custom model all your files and progress managed to same index
Then,

```
public void updateProgress(float percentage, int position){
    ProgPos = String.valueOf(position);
    Progress = (int) percentage;
    filePaths.get(position).setPercentage(percentage);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I already tried it. But it didn't work. That is the reason I posted this question. Without finding the progress bar position, how can the adapter knows to set the progress value to progress bar if we add this line "filePaths.set(position, String.valueOf(percentage));" If I add that line, it changes the file path text in the adapter not the progress bar or progress bar TextView. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: let me try this one